# .NET Expression Tree / Lambda Lifting framework?

Tags: .net, expression-trees

Anybody know of a nice package that allows implicit editing of Expression Trees? Since you can't really edit them, just returning a new tree would be fine. Easy methods for Lambda lifting (or 'funcletization') would be a nice bonus.

I remember a while back I was looking into this and I thought I found something but I can't remember the name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LINQ IQueryable Toolkit](https://web.archive.org/web/20180116001020/http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com:80/) and the [series of blog posts](https://web.archive.org/web/20160228161503/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx) from whence it came.

Comment: Excellent series of blog posts.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but close enough. thanks.

Comment: Was it maybe PredicateBuilder you were thinking of?  http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx